# mechanic left a part loose and i need help identifying where it should be attached

Tags: honda, part-identification, crv

Yesterday, I had the starter replaced on my 2009 Honda CR-V. After investigating a strange noise when the fan kicked in, I discovered what appears to be a bracket with some electrical connection on it was left unattached and had floated over to come in contact with the fan blade. The shop is closed today, and my wife needs to leave for work early in the morning.

[This image shows where my hand is holding a screwdriver that is touching the loose part.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qum5cwgp1srmpuq/IMG_2877.jpg?dl=0) It is on the driver side of the block.

[This picture shows the screwdriver tip touching the loose bracket part.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ml75epeix52g6q/IMG_2876.jpg?dl=0)

I don't see any obvious places where this should be attached. I have a Haynes basic repair manual for my car, but i haven't been successful in figuring out what type of component this is.

Can someone let me know: (a) what part is it that is loose? (b )How to go about re-attaching it, or if fixing it requires a tearing the engine apart how to secure it until I can get it back to the mechanic to fix their mistake.

[edit] this is the 2.4L engine

Comment: I would guess it is supposed to clip into the starter somewhere, but you won't be able to see where unless you get under the car (or put it on a ramp). If you just tie it down to anything so it can't hit any moving parts, it should be OK for a short time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Paulster2: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of zip ties, but they got the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not seeing in the image what you're talking about. In cases like this, if something does not appear to be structural in nature (supports something), using a zip tie will get you through until you can get it back to your mechanic. Just keeping it out of the way of the fan is the key.